# How do I find a vector space L that is linearly independent with a given vector space W if we know their union?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do we find $L$ if $L \ \oplus <(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,0)>  \ =  \ <(5,0,0,0),(2,-3,2,5),(0,0,1,1)>$, if $L$ is linearly independent to $<(1,0,1,1),(1,1,1,0)>$?

I normally find the determinants if I am finding vectors for the entire vector space [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrSPm.jpg), but that only works for $\Bbb R ^n$. I've checked but I haven't seen any methods to solve this. So, I don't have a way to prove that I've tried to solve it, except my rough workings.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on "[avoiding no-clue questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)")

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Note that $\oplus$ means direct sum, not "union." There will be more than one $L$ as a solution, unless you specify the direct sum is orthogonal too.

Comment: Thanks, just knew that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your aim is to find some subspace $L$ such that the linear hull

$$A \enspace := \enspace L \oplus \big< \; (1,0,1,1), (1,1,1,0) \; \big>$$

is equal to the linear hull

$$B \enspace := \enspace \big< \; (5,0,0,0) , (2,-3,2,5), (0,0,1,1) \; \big> \quad .$$

The first thing you could do is e.g. bringing $B$ into a nicer form. Since these vectors can be added and scaled among each other without changing the space they are spanning, they can be brought to the form:

$$B \enspace = \enspace \big< \; (1,0,0,0), (0,-1,0,1), (0,0,1,1) \; \big>$$

(check that)

Similarly, you can bring $A$ to the form

$$A \enspace = \enspace L \oplus \big< \; (1,0,1,1), (0,-1,0,1)  \; \big>$$

(check that).

One can immediatley see that the vector $(0,-1,0,1)$ is both in $A$ and $B$. So you are left to find some vector $x \in L$ such that $x$ and $(1,0,1,1) \in A$ span the space $\big< \; (1,0,0,0), (0,0,1,1) \; \big>$. Obviously it holds that

$$A \ni (1,0,1,1) = \Big( (1,0,0,0) + (0,0,1,1) \Big)\in B$$

So choosing e.g. $x = (1,0,0,0)$ should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but I made a mistake in the question. I thought the direct sum was the union of two linearly independent vector spaces.

Comment: I actually think that by "union" you mean the "sum" of vector spaces. An example to explain the difference: Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the linear hull of $(1,0)$ is the whole x-axis. The linear hull of $(0,1)$ is the whole y-axis. Now, the **union** (!) of these linear hulls $\big< (1,0) \big> \cup \big< (0,1) \big>$ are all vectors that are EITHER on the x-axis OR on the y-axis, whereas the **sum** (!) $\big< (1,0) \big> + \big< (0,1) \big>$ is the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2$. The **direct sum** is similar to the sum with the only restriction that both "summands" only share the zero-vector.

Comment: In other words, for two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ the following identity holds:

$$V + W = \big< V \cup W \big> = \operatorname{span} ( V \cup W)$$